# Is the Luna slice theorem valid for any orbit with a reductive stabilizer?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-groups

The Luna slice theorem states that if a reductive group $G$ acts on an affine space $X$ and $O$ is a closed orbit, then (in the  etale topology) there exists a $G$-invariant negihborhood of $O$ with a $G$-invariant projection. It seems that the proof uses only the fact that the stabilizer of any point in $O$ is reductive. Does the theorem hold in this generality? If yes - what is the reference?

Comment: You might be looking for Theorem 2.1 in  http://arxiv.org/abs/1504.06467

Comment: Ask Michel Brion (Michel.Brion@univ-grenoble-alpes.fr). He knows the answer.

Comment: It would help if you made more explicit what you mean here by "affine space", as well as what kind of field you work over and what kind of source you are following for Luna slices.   Aside from that, in the classical characteristic 0 setting for this theory, note that "reductive" is the same as "linearly reductive" in order to compare the passage Ariyan points to.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. Ariyan, It seems that you gave me exactly the answer  I need. Could you please post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar How much the assumption of closeness of the orbit is important for the existence of the etal slice? I mean does an analog of Luna's theorem hold for open orbits?

Answer (score 5):

There is already a counterexample in Luna's original paper (Remark 4 on p. 98). It is the $SL(2)$-orbit of $x^2y$ in the space of binary 3-forms. Luna attributes this example to Richardson.

Comment: Luna's slice theorem is much stronger than just asserting "the existence of a G-invariant etale neighborhood of O with a G-invariant projection". It also asserts that this neighborhood is a pull-back from X//G. In particular,  orbits are mapped isomorphically to orbits. The example above shows that this won't work for non-closed orbits. The weak version of the slice theorem is probably true.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think we need only the weaker version.